# Print array of object of array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am so confused about some datas. I am working with vanilla js.
I have an array like this.

```
rooms=[];
rooms.push({"room":"room1","users":[{"name":"arif"},{"name":"ozgur"}]});
rooms.push({"room":"room2","users":[{"name":"mehmet"},{"name":"hürol"}]});
```

I want to print users of room1.
I have tried

```
let activeroom = rooms.filter(room => room.room === "room1");
console.log(activeroom.users.toString());
```

But it didnt work. How can I access to names?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use find instead of filter

```js
rooms=[];
rooms.push({"room":"room1","users":[{"name":"arif"},{"name":"ozgur"}]});
rooms.push({"room":"room2","users":[{"name":"mehmet"},{"name":"hürol"}]});
let activeroom = rooms.find(room => room.room === "room1");
console.log(activeroom.users);
```

Answer (score 0):

your filter is right, but `activeroom` is array not object and you can't call `.toString()` for object use `JSON.stringify()` instead.

```js
rooms=[];
rooms.push({"room":"room1","users":[{"name":"arif"},{"name":"ozgur"}]});
rooms.push({"room":"room2","users":[{"name":"mehmet"},{"name":"hürol"}]});

let activeroom = rooms.filter(room => room.room === "room1");
console.log(JSON.stringify(activeroom));

console.log(JSON.stringify(activeroom[0].users)); // [0] select first index of object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let activeRooms = [];

rooms.forEach(eachRoom => {
  if (eachRoom.room === 'room1) {
      activeRooms.push(eachRoom);
  }
});

console.log('Active rooms array ==>', activeRooms);

// if you want to use your way of doing, implement filter inside the foreclosure. It will work. 

Room.room is not a property .. room is an array. So you'll have to loop through every room obj
```